# WCF Service with asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have started using asp.net MVC and as traditional way I want to keep my data access layer in WCF service. How can I achieve that using asp.net MVC ?

Scenario

I started a test application in asp.net MVC which Displays, Inserts and Edit data.
I successfully created that by adding 'ADO.Net Entity Data Model'.

So now if I wanted to move this dataaccess layer in WCF service, i.e. a WCF service with methods like GetData(), UpdateData(), CreateNewData(), how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Short Answer:

You just need to move your dataaccess layer into a WCF service, expose it and then call it from your MVC application.

Long Answer:

1) I recommend going through Scott Guthrie's [Nerd Dinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) walkthrough to get a really good understanding of MVC basics.

2) The following blog goes through the process of writing a Layered ASP.NET MVC Applicaiton with a WCF Service (Parts III & IV specifically concentrate on WCF & MVC interaction):

- [Part I](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-i/) (General Concepts)
- [Part II](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-ii/) (Building a Repository)
- [Part III](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-iii/) (Building The Service)
- [Part IV](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-iv/) (Using The Service)

I haven't read the linked arrticles in detail (just skimmed them) but they seem to give a decent overview of the process.

Comment: i like those blogs. been looking for something like this using mvc with wcf.

Answer (score -1):

**Asp.net MVC Application With Wcf Service**
http://patilranjeet.blogspot.in/2014/11/aspnet-mvc-with-wcf-sample.html