# Which's the best performance between Asp.net MVC controller VS. Wcf for Silverlight Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, performance

I found that Asp.net Mvc controller can serve both Asp.net Mvc View and Silverlight application via DynamicActionResult(It can be Simple Action Result or Json Action Result depend on request type). So, I have 3 options for creating middle-tier for Silverlight application.

1. **Pure WCF Service** Every request to WCF must be declare in interface. So, it's strongly-typed connection.
2. **Asp.net MVC Controller** It can serve both Asp.net MVC View and Silverlight application at the same time.
3. **Using both of them** I found that it's possible to doing this by using the answer in the following link. I think, It doesn't good idea for creating both of them.

[WCF Service with Asp.net MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943712/wcf-service-with-asp-net-mvc-application)

Which's the best performance between WCF Service and Asp.net MVC Controller?

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the kind of service that would benefit from caching?  If so, my testing says that MVC with Output Caching turned on is very much faster than WCF.

Comment: Have you ever tested on WCF caching by using SQL caching or custom caching?

Comment: Well, WCF caching is a different beast than output caching.  There are some variables here, but almost by definition, Output Caching is going to be faster.  That's because, in output caching, the request is returned so early in the pipeline.  Of course, if your services don't benefit from caching, all bets are off ;)