# Consuming JSON WCF/asmx service in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I want to consume a JSON/ WCF service in asp.net MVC 3 application. Do I need to use  Jquery AJAX or I can call service methods directly ? Do I need to create two projects in my solution. One for MVC 3 and One for WCF service ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following two links might be helpful

http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/06/13/using-the-wcf-web-api-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx

[WCF Service with asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943712/wcf-service-with-asp-net-mvc-application)